# disabling Commit Finished dialog in Tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is driving me nuts. Why should I need this really doing so many commits?

I attempted using TortoiseProc.exe with /closeonend:1 option set but it does not seem to work. That is, I enter commit message, click OK and then "commit finished" message box still shows up.

Perhaps this is related to the fact that I have post-commit hook script plugged in?

Comment: _"Perhaps this is related to the fact that I have post-commit hook script plugged in?"_ Probably not, did you set it up using the TortoiseSVN Hook Scripts UI?

Comment: re hook script ui: Yes.

Comment: Can you move it to the server, then try the aforementioned `TortoiseProc.exe with /closeonend:1` ? Sounds like a [bug report](http://tortoisesvn.net/reportbug.html) should be made ...

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "moving it to the server" - do you mean unrelated change that will trigger error so that those different /closenonend: values can be tested (no errors, no merges and conflicts, etc per documentation). I'm willing to test this of course I am just not sure what action I should undertake here.

Comment: I mean, move the hook script to the server as a [repository script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks). But first, totally remove the hook script from TortoiseSVN (make a backup of the script, of course) then try the auto-close option again.

Comment: I deleted post hook script, ran the command from the cmdline (regular dos window, no administrator privileges) and still got the same effect. Edit: oops sorry that window happened to run as Administrator, see below

Comment: command: "C:\soft\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:commit /path:"C:\my\workingcopy" /logmsg:"Branch ..., test" /closeonend:1

Comment: Got the reason: the msg box stays if I start the tortoiseproc.exe from Autohotkey script that happens to run as Administrator. When I run from regular dos window /closeonend:1 works as expected.

Comment: Interesting! So your `TortoiseProc.exe` does not run elevated? You should put that up as the answer and mark it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem:

1. /closenonend:1 works when TortoiseProc.exe is started using DOS window, whether as regular user or elevated (Administrator)
2. it does NOT work when started using AutoHotkey (that runs TortoiseProc.exe) running as Administrator (elevated).

The reason I run AHK as Administrator is that AHK can then override Windows 8 hotkey combinations.

What's even more puzzling is that when I start batch script from that elevated AHK that runs TortoiseProc.exe (i.e. AHK/Administrator -> batch script -> TortoiseProc.exe), /closeonend:1 works as expected!

It's probably some subtle bug in AHK or a subtle ramification of how Windows 8 permissions are designed.